# Door jamb and molding too short after replacing carpet with hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, door-frame, jamb

I've recently replaced carpet with hardwood floor. The door jamb and molding are now too short. Prior, the carpet was plusher and made the gap in this one door jamb less obvious.

Door Jamb
[image: Door Jamb]

Molding
[image]

I'm pretty sure I am going to replace the molding anyways, to a more modern style.

My question, can the jamb somehow be repaired? With wood filler that can be sanded and painted perhaps? Is it faster to just replace the door jamb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to replace the molding, I would replace the jam as well.  I looks to me like you are due for an upgrade in all of your wood-work. With the new floors and new wood-work, I think you would see a marked improvement in the overall look of he space.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I'll add this for others to reference:

You can drop the door & frame fairly easily.  If you are replacing the casing on both sides of the door, you can essentially "remove & reinstall" the door and frame (youtube is your friend).  Then the gap at the bottom of the door will be correct as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yea, I don't really see any way of getting around replacing the jamb and molding.